# Filter out classes before doing a prediction with a multi-class classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I built a multi-class classifier with Keras and want to improve my results by filtering out classes I know won't be useful for a certain datapoint, before doing a prediction. In other words, narrow down the possibilities as much as possible before giving the hand to the model. In my case I am classifying handwritten characters and digits, and sometimes I know that some inputs for instance can't be `[A, B, F, K, 0, 3, 8, 9]`. Filtering these out will definitely help, removing for example the ambiguity than can arise when classifying a `0` or an `O`.

Here is the model's summary:

```
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_20 (Conv2D)           (None, 24, 24, 32)        832       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_20 (MaxPooling (None, 12, 12, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 64)          51264     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_21 (MaxPooling (None, 4, 4, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_10 (Flatten)         (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_10 (Dropout)         (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 128)               131200    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 30)                3870      
=================================================================
Total params: 187,166
Trainable params: 187,166
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The last fully connected layer has the softmax activation function. However, the outcome of a prediction using `model.predict()`, `model.predict_classes()` or `model.predict_proba()` will only yield results such as `[0, 0, 1, 0, ..., 0]`. I know this should be the probability of each class, but I always get all `0` and a single `1`. To verify this isn't due to overfitting, I trained the model for a single epoch, reaching only ~60% accuracy (while if I continued the training I'd reach ~94%).
If I had access to the probabilities of each classes I could do the filtering after the prediction. But since it only really outputs a single class, I can't risk filtering it out and ending up with a bunch of `0`.

Is there a way I can get classes' probabilities, or filter out classes before the prediction, to avoid training multiple models for each sub-group of classes ? To avoid misunderstandings, here is a bit more information: I am training a model on the emnist dataset (characters and digits) to classify my own data made of similar images of characters and digits. However, my data is divided into multiple groups, some of them I know can't contain certain characters or digits. The model is trained with all classes (all digits and chars) and when I say "training multiple models" I mean training models with different subsets of classes (for instance only [A, B, 0, 1, 2, 3], which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: How about do the prediction and find which one is not matched with gt? Before that how would you know which class's input would go wrong?

Comment: I will add more details to the post.

Comment: model.predict() returns probability only. You can ignore the classes which are not relevant and find max from the rest of them.

Comment: @Mukul as I mention in the post, I'm somehow only getting probabilities of `1` and `0`. This prevents me from doing what you suggest, which I also mention in the post.

Comment: @NawraC that's weird, check the datatype it should be float32.

Comment: @Mukul `model.predict()` does output a float32 array.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a Lambda layer that masks out the irrelevant logits before the softmax activation (i.e., a 30-long vector of 1's and 0's is added as an input to your model as well). If you have the data you are talking about a-priori, you could even train your model with it to yield better results.

Comment: The thing is during the training I don't have any a priori information regarding which classes should be opted out (I am using the emnist dataset for training). I only have this information when trying to do a prediction on my own data.

Comment: @NawraC given that detail (which should be actually part of your question, and not casually revealed in a comment), I am afraid that what you ask does not make any sense at all; during inference the information will simply flow through the fitted model, and even if the info  was available it would not be usable. It is also completely unclear what you mean by "*training multiple models*" in the last sentence of your post, when all the discussion until then is for a single model.

Comment: I am training a model on the emnist dataset (characters and digits) to classify my own data made of similar images of characters and digits. However, my data is divided into multiple groups, some of them I know can't contain certain characters or digits. The model is trained with all classes (all digits and chars) and when I say "training multiple models" I mean training models with different subsets of classes (for instance only `[A, B, 0, 1, 2, 3]`, which I'm trying to avoid. Mumuk in the comments correctly understood the post, could you explain what more information you'd like to know ?

Comment: Also, I do mention in the post that it is during the prediction that I have knowledge of which classes to filter out. It's actually the first line of the post. I'd like whoever downvoted it to explain more clearly why it's a bad post.